# programmatic control of application's perception of time

Tags: virtual-machine, clock

I'm looking to be able to control an application's perception of time from another process. Meaning I want to be able to fast-forward the clock. Whether by accelerating it, or stepping, either would be acceptable (though stepping would be safer & easier).

I know there is `faketime`, but that's not suitable for my needs as it can't handle scenarios such as a call to `sleep(10)` or `epoll_wait(,,,10000)`, and then while that's blocking, advancing the clock 15 seconds. In this case, the call will still take 10 seconds to complete. This makes sense as these are system calls, and thus it's the kernel which is tracking elapsed time.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is replay recorded network traffic through an application. At the time of processing each recorded event, the application needs to see the event as if the amount of time since the previous event actually has passed. Meaning if the log has one event at `00:01:00` and another event at `00:01:07`, when replaying the app needs to think 7 seconds have passed (absolute time doesn't matter, just relative time). As this traffic might have been recorded over hours, I don't want to have to take that long to perform the replay. So the idea is to fast-forward the clock during each of the idle periods, as if that time had naturally passed. These "idle periods" may be a few milliseconds long (~80ms would be a likely example), but there's thousands to millions of them.

I suspect I may have to resort to running the application inside a VM, and then controlling the VM's clock from outside the VM. This is fine, but I'm having trouble finding whether any hypervisor is capable of doing that.

I've tried simply adjusting the clock of the linux kernel, but this doesn't handle the `sleep(10)` scenario described above (it still sleeps for 10 seconds even if clock skips past the scheduled end).

Comment: You could leverage `installwatch`'s interception of system calls with `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept the timing calls, and lie to the program.

Comment: That's exactly what `faketime` does, and thus suffers the same problem.